# Положение скролла страницы js

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка

Я хочу сделать так:
1. js/jquery узнаёт позицию скролла страницы (пиксели сверху)
2. Передаёт это в форму 
3. После редиректа на начальную страницу  возпроизвести там положение скролла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

**1**) Получаем положение скрола и переводим в строку:

```
const scrollPosotion = window.scrollY.toString();`
```

**2**) Просто передаёшь в FormData или как ты отправляешь данные, либо через localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('last_pos', scrollPosotion);
```

**3**) Как перешёл на стартовую страницу берёшь данные которые отправлял с формы либо через localStorage:

```
const lastScrollPosition = parseInt( localStorage.getItem('last_pos') );
```

И отправляем пользователя на последнюю позицию:

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: lastScrollPosition // переменная после перехода.
 }, 1500);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Обращайся если что:)